# Batch Script: Can We set a String with space in SET /p command?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

for example,
code;

```
:void.loop
    set command=
    set /P command=
    if %command%=="this is a test" goto :void.loop
```

now, i am writing "
**this is a test** " in the command promp...

the output is;

**"is==" Unexpected For This Time**

can you guys help for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put quotes around your variable. I would also add a space before and after `==` for readability, but that's not necessary.

```
if "%command%" == "this is a test" goto :void.loop
```

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure batch takes the if statement very literally. It will use the quotes as part of the search and the space too. So it would compare "quote"space to space"this is a test" and thus fail.

Comment: yes, it will work in the exact strings.

but what i want to create a Text editor, or Text creator?

so i can't use "==" in there, i need to use;

```bat
(
echo %command%
) >> test.txt
```

Comment: or most importantly; when i am writing wrong something; like **"this is a _tst_"**... i don't want to it is going to crash.

Answer (score 0):

for if Commands;

```
:void.loop
    set command=
    set /P command=
    if /i "%command%"=="" goto :void.loop
    if "%command%"=="help" call :void.help
    if "%command%"=="cls" cls
    if "%command%"=="exit" exit
    goto :void.loop
```

for echo or write to TXT;

```
set /p asd=
(
echo %asd%
) > test.txt
```